# Exlude IP from Ettercap Hosts

Tags: linux, man-in-the-middle

I am messing around with Ettercap and performing some MITM on my own home network.

I have Ettercap performing the MITM fine.  I have my iPhone on the network and it autoadds the iPhone.  I then run urlsnarf to view the websites I am visiting and that works perfectly also.  However.  The machine I am performing the MITM attack from appears in the urlsnarf logs.  Does anyone know of a way to exclude the machine that I am running the MITM from being picked up by Ettercap?

Here is the command I am running to start Ettercap:

sudo ettercap -T -P autoadd -Q -M ARP -i eth0 /192.168.0.1/ /192.168.0.2-100/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific 'exclude' option I know of for Ettercap that will explicitly exclude a target from view, while still allowing you to only include that 192.168.0.2-100 range you have.

However, you can reverse the target specification using the -R switch, and get basically the same result, though you give up the ability to fine tune your target.  Basically, Ettercap allows you to only exclude **OR** include, not both.

Look under TARGET SPECIFICATION in the Ettercap docs at http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/ettercap for more info.

Also, you also can use the parameters of urlsnarf to only collect data from a specific host using a tcpdump(8) filter too.  http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/urlsnarf

And honestly, did you try just using an IP address on your monitoring computer that is out of range of the target spec?  You are using /192.168.0.2-100/, assigning your IP to 192.168.0.101 would keep it from being MITM'ed by Ettercap. This seems to be the most obvious way, so I'm wondering why bother with a post.

Remember that depending on a host of factors, the use of these tools will be either perfectly legal, or totally illegal. Ignorance of the law is no defense. DunDunDun

Comment: THanks for this.  Will look into some of these options.  I am aware of the legalities of this but it is all on my home network just for fun.